# API Rest Nginx cannot get

Tags: node.js, http, express, nginx, reverse-proxy

I've been develop an API with Express and Node.js. I have a simple routes and need to setup Nginx as a reverse proxy (following this steps: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-node-js-application-for-production-on-ubuntu-16-04#set-up-nginx-as-a-reverse-proxy-server) but when I create a GET request my browser says: "Cannot GET /video/GetVideo/some_id".

Node code:

```
_apiRoutes = express.Router();
_apiRoutes.get('/video/GetVideo/:VideoID', (req, res) => {
    getVideo(req.params, (result) => {
        res.json(result);
    });
});

_apiRoutes.get('*', function (req, res) {
    res.status(404).send('yay!, are you lost?');
});

app.use('/api', _apiRoutes);
```

last code generate a route like: http://some_url/api/video/GetVideo/:VideoID

Nginx code:

```
    ... 
    location / {
            # First attempt to serve request as file, then
            # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
            #try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header x-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_pass http://localhost:3500;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
```

Comment: Your nginx config appears to be trying to strip off the `/api/` part of the path using `rewrite` but then you seem to be expecting it to still be there in your Express routing. Could you clarify your intent?

Comment: I'm sorry, this is a test trying to solve my problem, I edited the answer.

Comment: I don't know why, but my problem is resolved removed these lines, you know the reason?